# Setup in virtualenv: `pip install -e .` vs `python setup.py install`

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, setup.py

I'm following a Flask tutorial that has me using `virtualenv`, and with it I built an app directory tree that looks like this:

```
app/
|__app/
|__app.egg-inf/
|__setup.py
|__venv/
```

Inside my `venv` the tutorial tells me to run `pip install -e .` which appears to be using my `setup.py` to install dependencies and my application.

Why does the tutorial have me running `pip install -e .`? Why not `python setup.py install`? What are the differences?

(FWIW, `export FLASK_APP=app; flask run` works fine after `pip install -e .` but doesn't work after a `python setup.py install`)

Answer (score 20):

First, the commands you mention are not equivalent, specifically `python setup.py install` does not give you an editable installation. The `pip <-> python setup.py` equivalents are:

```
Editable   pip                    setup.py
yes        pip install -e .       python setup.py develop    
no         pip install .          python setup.py install
```

With that said, using `pip` is in general recommended for a range of reasons:

- Dependencies are automatically installed
- There is an easy way to uninstall

In your case, I highly suspect that your package has a dependency which is automatically installed if you use pip, but not if you use `python setup.py install`.

Comment: I believe the Feb 21 edit put "install" and "develop" under setup.py on the wrong lines.