# pip - Installing dependencies with <local project path>. Using `pip install -e`

Tags: python-3.x, pip, gensim

I want to understand how `pip install -e <local project path>` works. [The references](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#usage) tell the `<local project path>` should have a setup.py file but doesn't mention anything else.

Does the `-e` flag executes setup.py file? Or are there some other steps involved?

Also, I see [projects](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/issues/1519#issuecomment-339700695) using the command like this: `pip install -e .[test]`. What does `.[test]` mean? Is it value placeholder that is defined somewhere? Is it a folder name? Or is it specific to how I write my `setup.py`? I couldn't find such example usage in the [`pip install` references](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/issues/1519#issuecomment-339700695).

Comment: Yes, `pip install -e` calls `setup.py develop` which creates links to code in place. `[]` means to install `extra` packages, so `.[test]` mean also install the extra `test` packages in the current project as in `<local project path> == '.'` (see https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/#installing-setuptools-extras)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45426794/setup-in-virtualenv-pip-install-e-vs-python-setup-py-install

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+%22install+-e%22